# Got message: FATAL: expected SASL response, got message type 88

Tags: postgresql-13

I have a strange situation. A small program working fine till these days (about half a year). The program (NodeJS) is creating a local connection to DB:

```
1st: creating new connection to local db.
2nd: client by websocket connected to this program, and program creating a new connection for client.
```

In NodeJS both connections creating in same way, like:

```
1st: const client=new PgClient(connection string)
2nd: const networkClient=new PgClient(connection string)
```

Then now the 2nd connection is giving this error to Postgresql logs - `FATAL: expected SASL response, got message type 88`. While the 1st connection is working fine.

Before everything was working fine. What the reason can be? I've googled, but strange that exactly for such error message there are no results.

**UPD:** It seem I found the reason, it's in the code. The connect method requires `await`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my js script, the websocket server has no timeout option for ping-pong activities. And thus, terminated all clients immediatelly.